# Facebook Login in Coldfusion

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to login via Facebook using Coldfusion. I am stuck here how to display Login button and which `.cfc` i include to do this.
First I download the SDK from this website [Facebook Coldfusion SDK](https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk)
and then I include

```
 <cfinclude template="facebook-cf-sdk/sdk/FacebookApp.cfc">
```

and then add this code to get Login button

```
    <p><fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>
```

but I dont find any button into my browser.
Can someone tell me how to do this I am new in coldfusion please someone help me how to connect with facebook.
I googled and search many tutorials but no one tell the basic steps to add this button.
thanks waiting for positive response

Answer (score 2):

The cfinclude tag is used with .cfm or .html files.  To gain access to the code in a .cfc file, you have to create an object with either the CreateObject() function or the cfobject tag.

Comment: To clarify your first line, cfinclude treats all files as CFML "templates" (flat scripts), irrespective of extension.

Since CFCs are not templates (they are components/objects), they need to be invoked in a different way (i.e. createObject/etc) to work.

Comment: I have a CFC which consists of a single cfinclude to another cfc. That cfc is later instantiated with a createObject(). It is a hack

Answer (score 1):

On https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk/blob/master/examples/website/index.cfm

The following code is used:

```
import facebook.sdk.FacebookApp;
import facebook.sdk.FacebookGraphAPI;
```

Later these are instantiated with

```
if (APP_ID is "" or SECRET_KEY is "") {
    // App not configured
    facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI();
} else {
    // Create facebookApp instance
    facebookApp = new FacebookApp(appId=APP_ID, secretKey=SECRET_KEY);
```

Additional documentation on import and new can be found at

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS61C07B60-3D65-4d71-8F2A-8411D8010E60.html

Comment: It gives me error in `facebook.sdk.FacebookApp` and error is `Invalid CFML construct found on line 558 at column 78. ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

{

The CFML compiler was processing:

    A script statement beginning with private on line 558, column 9.`

Comment: Struct parameters = {} might only work on later versions of CF 9. I think that is a CF 9.01. You may have to replace it with StructNew()